# Send a Quit message to Qt app with event loop from another process in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I've created a server using Qt and `QTcpServer`. It runs in the background and doesn't show any windows, but it uses an event loop.

My main.cpp looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyServer theServer;
    return a.exec();
}
```

How do I notify my server to close, without resorting to `TerminateProcess()`? I'm fine with a Windows-only solution, so I can use WINAPI functions if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just implemented it using `QLocalServer`. It turned out to be very easy:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    static const char *quitSignalName = "My Service Quit Signal";

    const QStringList &args = a.arguments();
    if (args.size() == 2 && args[1] == "--shutdown") {
        // Connect to the named pipe to notify the service it needs
        // to quit. The QLocalServer will then end the event loop.
        QLocalSocket quitSignal;
        quitSignal.connectToServer(quitSignalName);
        quitSignal.waitForConnected();
        return 0;
    }

    // Listen for a quit signal, we connect the newConnection() signal
    // directly to QApplication::quit().
    QLocalServer quitSignalWatcher;
    QObject::connect(&quitSignalWatcher, SIGNAL(newConnection()), &a, SLOT(quit()));
    quitSignalWatcher.listen(quitSignalName);

    MyServer theServer;
    Q_UNUSED(theServer);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending upon what the server is for, as you're using TCPServer, you could send it a message to tell it to quit, though you may want to authenticate who is sending that message.

Alternatively, have a controller application on the same machine that can talk to the server via a named pipe, which you can use to tell it to quit.